# changing meter value dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, arduino

I am a total beginner of HTML and JavaScript, anyway I am trying to update a meter in my code with a value coming from a arduino.

It works in the original code with updating numbers (first row of the code) but I want to have the value presented in a meter. This code works but I want to change the static value "100" in the meter as it is here to get the value of "P1" instead, I have tried a lot of things but nothing works (this is probably easy but I'm a beginner), would appreciate help.

```
<li>State of POT: <span id="P1" class="highlight">...</span>. To update this value, rotate the knob of POT.</li>


 <script>
swduino_stream("P","P1","onoff_led");

function onoff_led(value)
{

document.getElementById("myMeter").setAttribute("value","100");
}
 </script>

<p>Panna: <meter id="myMeter" min="0" low="245" high="250" max="280" value="0"></meter></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onoff_led function have you checked what is being set to it ?

If it is being sent the current value, then you can just change your update for myMeter to update the value with your value parameter sent to the function.

```
function onoff_led(value)
{

document.getElementById("myMeter").setAttribute("value", value);
}
```

If you can not check what the onoff_led function is receiving i.e. debug because it is inline javascript then create a seperate javascript file which contains the function and load that at top of the page. You can then set a break point to find out what is being set to the function.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks a lot this really did it. I really appreciated Your help and now I can move forward in my project.

Comment: @Svempa Good news, if you can mark this as the correct answer. It will give me much required Rep and also close the question :) All the best with the project.